# Liking a YouTube comment from the app

Tags: youtube

I've been using Android for a few months now, and I'm mostly happy with it. I just can't find the "Like" button for comments.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its still not possible to thumbs up or down a comment using the Youtube app. People have been complaining for years about it.

Comment: its 2017 and they still havent fixed this. Thats kind of ridiculous given how huge youtube and android are!

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned in the earlier Answer, as of this writing, there is **no way** to Like comments in Android YouTube App.

Below is the screen shot confirming this, taken from Official link.[image]

Source [Link](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6000964?hl=en)